# Web Deploy Packages fail on build server

Tags: silverlight, tfs, tfsbuild

I am using the following MSBuild command form the command prompt:

```
MSBuild.exe /nologo "Server.Website.csproj" /T:Package
```

on a web application (ASP.NET 4 MVC) that relies on a project reference to a Silverlight project.  When building, I get the following error:

```
"C:\Builds\2\Development\Main Branch Nightly\Sources\Components\Server.Website\Server.Website.csproj" (Package target) (1) ->
(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackage target) ->
C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(1852,5): error : Copying file Content\ClientBin\Shell.xap to obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\Content\ClientBin\Shell.xap failed. Could not find a part of the path 'Content\ClientBin\Shell.xap'.
[C:\Builds\2\Development\Main Branch Nightly\Sources\Components\Server.Website\Server.Website.csproj]
```

When I omit the `/T:Package` from the MSBuild call, it seems to work fine.  Am I missing something about handing XAPs for build servers on silverlight?

Comment: Looks like the output of your Silverlight project may be getting redirected on the build server. Have you checked to see if it exists on a different path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Server.Website.csproj` project, under

```
<Project>
   <PropertyGroup>
      <SilverlightApplicationList>
```

the path to the XAP's project was incorrect.  Fixing this issue corrected the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing worth trying is to change "Build Action" and "Copy to Output Directory" on your ClientBin\silverlight.xap file

Answer (score 0):

open task manager and kill MSBuild.exe processess, then rebuild the projects

worked for me